# Bootstrap 3: Fixed Top Navbar won't hide when zoomed on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

While using Chrome on a Galaxy S3, when zooming, the fixed menu doesn't disappear. On other devices such as an iPhone, the menu will hide. Since the menu won't hide, it covers half the content of the viewing area.

I was able to replicate this on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/.

It's not a major problem, but visually not ideal. Any one run into this?
Here is a screenshot of what is happening. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV0Vq.jpg